# backbone.js how to use variables as selectors in events

Tags: events, variables, backbone.js, selector

In Backbone.js I am trying to use a variable as a selector to bind to an event like this:

```
events: function() {
    var _events = {};
    _events["click " + "#plus-" + this.options.count] = "add";
    return _events;
}
```

Some (or more than one) thing must be wrong because Backbone seems to ignore it.

Most examples I've seen here use class and not id selectors. Is there a reason for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to say that I don't understand this *dynamic events declaration* need. But I suppose you have your reasons.

Any how I've come up with a working solution that looks like this:

```
// html
<div id="container">
    <button id="button-1">button 1</button>
    <button id="button-2">button 2</button>
</div>​

// js
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: function(){
        var _events = {};
        _events["click " + "#button-" + this.options.count] = "buttonClick";
        return _events;
    },
    buttonClick: function(){
        console.log( "click() on button " + this.options.count );
    }
});

var view1 = new View({
    el: $('#container'),
    count: 1
});


var view2 = new View({
    el: $('#container'),
    count: 2
});
```

Check the [working jsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/PLXXz/)

So, either I'm missing something or the issue is somewhere else.

About using `class` or `id` in your *events css selector* it is just up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Although I didn't change it, my code (essentially the same as yours) works too!

Comment: you could also use _extend on an object